При начальной миграции создается дополнительный FK ***EntityId
Столкнулся с такой проблемой при начальной миграции создается FK EmployeeEntityId, в чем может быть причина?
Участок схемы

Модели:
public class EmployeeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateOnly HiringDate { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? DateOfDismissal {  get; set; }
    public string? Description {  get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity? User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DepartmentEntity> Department { get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<ReceptionEntity> Reception { get; set; } = [];
}

public class DepartmentEntity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public int AdressId {  get; set; }
    public AdressEntity? Adress { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmployeeEntity> Employee { get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<ReceptionEntity> Reception { get; set; } = []; 
}

public class EmployeeDepartmentEntity
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public int PositionId {  get; set; }
    public PositionEntity? Position { get; set; }
}

Конфигурации
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EmployeeEntity> builder)
 {
     builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

     builder
         .Property(x => x.HiringDate)
         .IsRequired();

     builder
         .Property(x => x.Description)
         .HasMaxLength(250);

     builder
         .HasMany(x => x.Reception)
         .WithOne(x => x.Employee);

     builder
         .HasOne(e => e.User)
         .WithOne(e => e.Employee)
         .HasForeignKey<EmployeeEntity>(e => e.UserId)
         .IsRequired();

     builder.HasMany(r => r.Department)
         .WithMany(p => p.Employee)
         .UsingEntity<EmployeeDepartmentEntity>(
             r => r.HasOne<DepartmentEntity>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentId),
             l => l.HasOne<EmployeeEntity>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId));
 }

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DepartmentEntity> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder
        .Property(x => x.Name)
        .HasMaxLength(60)
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .Property(x => x.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(250);

    builder
        .HasOne(x => x.Adress)
        .WithOne(y => y.Department)
        .HasForeignKey<DepartmentEntity>(x => x.AdressId);

    builder.HasMany(r => r.Employee)
        .WithMany(p => p.Department)
        .UsingEntity<EmployeeDepartmentEntity>(
            l => l.HasOne<EmployeeEntity>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId),
            r => r.HasOne<DepartmentEntity>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentId));

    builder
        .HasMany(x => x.Reception)
        .WithOne(x => x.Department);

}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EmployeeDepartmentEntity> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(r => new { r.EmployeeId, r.DepartmentId });

    builder
        .Property(x => x.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(250);

    builder
        .HasOne(x => x.Position)
        .WithMany(x => x.EmployeeDepartment)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.PositionId);
}

Генерируемая миграция
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "EmployeesDepartments",
    columns: table => new
    {
        EmployeeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        DepartmentId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(250)", maxLength: 250, nullable: true),
        PositionId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        EmployeeEntityId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_EmployeesDepartments", x => new { x.EmployeeId, x.DepartmentId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_EmployeesDepartments_Departments_DepartmentId",
            column: x => x.DepartmentId,
            principalTable: "Departments",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_EmployeesDepartments_Employees_EmployeeEntityId",
            column: x => x.EmployeeEntityId,
            principalTable: "Employees",
            principalColumn: "Id");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_EmployeesDepartments_Employees_EmployeeId",
            column: x => x.EmployeeId,
            principalTable: "Employees",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_EmployeesDepartments_Positions_PositionId",
            column: x => x.PositionId,
            principalTable: "Positions",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

